# Who was the first philosopher who explicitly connected belief with habit formation?

Tags: philosophy-of-science, history-of-philosophy, psychology

Aristotle speaks about habit but I can't find anywere in his works any explicit connection of habit with belief.

> Is there any subsequent philosopher who explicitly connected belief
> with habit formation?

Comment: [Hume on causation](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/hume/#Cau)

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA Isn't there any philosopher who expounded any relation between belief and habit more clearly than Hume?

Comment: Habit is obviously related to one's belief thus hard to pinpoint exactly who's the first philosopher to connect them explicitly. The whole ancient Surangama sutra expounding Buddhism philosophy explicitly discussed habit and the way to break out as ref [here](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama17.asp.html): *You have already extinguished the view-delusions of living beings in the three realms, but you do not yet know that your organs have accumulated habits that are without beginning... Extremely subtle, the Adana consciousness. Makes patterns of habit that flow on in torrents...*